# Get all options from Android Spinner using Appium

Tags: appium

I am trying to pull all the options off an android spinner, using Appium. With Selenium, you can use the Select object and do something like getOptions (I forget the exact syntax). I need the text from all the options in the spinner.

Comment: pls post the spinner screenshot and uiautomator pointing on the elements

Comment: That isn't necessary to provide the answer to my question.

Comment: ur understanding wont be the same of a person who havent seen your app

Comment: Agree with karthick23

Comment: That makes zero sense. The app doesn't matter. I am talking about an element, a Spinner. It behaves the same no matter what. I am talking about a generic problem, getting the values of the options on the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the spinner options are accessible through Appium. Getting all the values of the options on the spinner shall work as follows :

```
List<WebElement> spinnerList = driver.findElements(getBy("identifier")); //where identifier would vary on how you can access the elements 
String spinnerListElementText[index]; //e.g. to store Text of all the options
for (int index = 0; index < spinnerList.size(); index++) {
        String spinnerListElementText[index] = spinnerList.get(index).getText();
}
```

Comment: This will only return the visible options. I am trying to get ALL the options

Comment: You're probably hitting the hot iron..currently appium is not providing an access to objects not visible unless you `scrollTo` that object or `swipe` on screen to make them visible.

Comment: so how can I swipe on the spinner? when I try to do something like 'Appium::TouchAction.new.swipe(....)' it is saying the swipe did not complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In Appium, there are test frameworks called Uiautomator, Uiautomator2 and Espresso, respectively. The thing that you were trying to get is not provided by Uiautomator or Uiautomator2 test frameworks. The only way with those frameworks is to click the spinner and get page source of spinner with visible elements. You could try to use Espresso framework. This is the reason:

**Uiautomator:** It is a test framework which provides a black-box testing for developers. It means that you can not get internal codes of the application.

**Espresso:** It is a test framework which provides a ***grey-box*** testing for developers. It means that you can get internal codes of the application, find elements which are not visible in the page (off-screen elements).

Try to use Espresso framework in Appium.